# Retrieve distinct values from Mongodb using Mongodb.Driver

Tags: mongodb, vb.net, mongodb-query, mongodb-.net-driver

I am trying to return a list of distinct file types from a MongoDB collection using VB.Net (similar to C#.Net). Since each document has an unique `id` regardless of similar file types, the code returns duplicates. What am I missing here? I tried `GroupBy` but it didn't work.

```
Public Function GetAllFileTypes() As List(Of UXFiles)
        Dim m_List As New List(Of UXFiles)

        Dim db As IMongoDatabase = DatabaseService.GetDBcontext()
        Dim files = db.GetCollection(Of BsonDocument)("Files").Find(New BsonDocument).ToList
        m_List = files.Select(Function(_file) ConvertFile(_file)).Distinct().ToList()

        Return m_List
    End Function


    Private Function ConvertFile(fileDocument As BsonDocument) As UXFiles

        Dim file As New UXFiles With {
            .ID = If(fileDocument.Contains("id"), fileDocument.GetElement("id").Value.ToString, ""),
            .Name = If(fileDocument.Contains("name"), fileDocument.GetElement("name").Value.ToString, ""),
            .Type = If(fileDocument.Contains("type"), fileDocument.GetElement("type").Value.ToString, "")
        }
        Return file
    End Function
```

Comment: Distinct works on the entire object/record in the query result set.  If you're after a list of distinct filenames, just query the filename property only

Comment: Or not sure if it works, but maybe a custom predicate for Distinct?

Comment: @Hursey can you provide some sample code or snippet of what you mean?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Distinct eliminates duplicate results from the result set. If you include _id of each document in the results, there are no duplicates since each _id is unique. You need to either project some fields (e.g. file type if you want to know what file types exist) or use something like $group with $first.

Answer (score 0):

Just for future if anyone needs the code sample I am posting the answer. Although @D.SM's idea helped me to fix the issue.

To solve the issue I used `Project` to exclude unique value which is `_id` and then I grouped the results by the property `type` in my case.

```
  Public Function GetAllFileTypes() As List(Of UXFiles)

        Dim m_List As New List(Of UXFiles)

        Dim db As IMongoDatabase = DatabaseService.GetDBcontext()
        Dim project = Builders(Of BsonDocument).Projection.Include("type").Exclude("_id")

        Dim bsonDocuments = db.GetCollection(Of BsonDocument)("Files").Find(New BsonDocument).Project(project).ToList
        m_List = bsonDocuments.Select(Function(_file) ConvertFile(_file)).ToList()

        Dim distinctList = m_List.GroupBy(Function(x) x.Type).Select(Function(x) x.First).ToList


        Return distinctList
  End Function
```